# NPN transistor as a switch configuration

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, resistors, bjt, npn

I have a npn transistor configured as a switch which is normally on and at times I have it switch off and on at 7Hz-8Hz, with R1 5.10k and R2 100k and 0 V to 5 V MCU pin and max \$I_C\$ current from 50-60 mA. With these values the \$I_B\$ come to be around 0.81-0.83 mA. Will this configuration values will okay in the long run or is a fail?, with this type of NPN transistor [transistor datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBT2222A.pdf). The circuit seems to operate okay, but should have lowered the Rth resistance to lower value to secure complete saturation like 2k and having a 5.10k not enough over time. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb for transistor switches is to make the base current 1/10th of the collector current to force it into saturation. This would put you at around
$$
R1 = \frac{V_{in}-V_{BE}}{I_B} = \frac{5.0V-0.7V}{6mA}= 716.\overline{666}\Omega
$$

so 720\$\Omega\$ should do it.

Answer (score 0):

> *Will this configuration values will okay in the long run or is a fail?*

and

> *max \$I_C\$ current from 50-60 mA.*

It comes down to how low you want the saturation voltage to be. Consider this [data sheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBT2222A.pdf) graph: -

[image]

If you want the saturation voltage to be less that 100 mV then you should adopt a value of \$I_C/I_B\$ of ten. If you can live with maybe 200 mV you can probably get away with \$I_C/I_B\$ being 20.